# Replace HTTP sessions in Cloud using REDIS cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, redis, cloud, httpsession

We have HTTP sessions in on-premise application. We want to migrate application to Cloud. We got the direction to use REDIS cache implementation in Cloud to replace HTTP sessions.

Do we save user specific(HTTP Session) data in REDIS? Is there any other elegant way to handle this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-faq#can-i-use-azure-cache-for-redis-as-a-php-session-cache

Comment: What do you do for HTTP session management right now? What language is your application written in? What relevant frameworks (middleware, session management, etc.) does it use right now?

Comment: It is legacy application and using Java servlets and JSPs. In app, we are pulling data from DB and keeping it in HTTP Session object and using it in other page by retrieving from session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a legacy app, you can set Redis (Azure Redis Cache) as your State Provider.

Here's a link about it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider

Comment: Yes Thiago, it is legacy Java app. HTTP sessions are meant to a user/session. My understanding on REDIS is, it  stores data which is useful for all nodes in Loadbalancer and we keep master data in it. Is it recommended to use HTTP session data in  REDIS?

Comment: you're correct. The link I provided is for asp.net but the idea is the same. Use Azure Redis Cache (Microsoft managed version of Redis) to share state between multiple instances

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and Redis is one of the pinpoint solutions for this kind of requirements. It is super fast in-memory key/value store just like sessions(get/set). Most of the modern frameworks come along with built-in session support for Redis. Even it is a legacy app, you may integrate easily(there could some libraries that do that). You may just use commands such as `SET`, `GET`, `EXPIRE`, `EXISTS`, `DEL` for a session store.

If it is going to be just string/string you may go with [string](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#strings), if you have some json values you may use [hash](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes). Both solutions provide `EXPIRE` option for you to not store forever and manage your memory.

I am not familiar with Azure side but AWS has [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) service that supports Redis. Another option could be installing one in a EC2 instance for on-prem.